# What this error message mean please: Ignoring request to auto-attach. It is disabled for org "15824072" because of the content access mode setting

Tags: shell, centos, rhel

When trying to subscribe my centos 8 to a redhat repos, I got the error bellow.
Can someone explains what do I need to do  ?

```
[root@thiecentos8 ~]# subscription-manager attach --auto

Ignoring request to auto-attach. It is disabled for org "15824072" because of the content access mode setting.
```

Comment: You can only do that if you have a RedHat subscription.

Answer (score 6):

Once a year, for the free Redhat subscriptions, the subscription will expire, this is telling us the pool doesn't have a valid subscription. The Redhat system will take maybe up to a half hour to reflect changes to the subscription. If your subscription expires it may be preferable to update the subscription on a non-Redhat computer. The network access will be limited on the Redhat machine with the expired subscription.

- Log into developer.redhat.com
- Click on your Avatar in the top right
- Go to Subscriptions... Overview
- Enable Simple content access
- Wait about 10 minutes, for whatever reason the Redhat/IBM back end takes time to process a transaction

First try just refreshing and re-attaching on the affected machine(s).

```
$ sudo -s
# subscription-manager refresh
# subscription-manager attach --auto --username=XXX --password=XXX, replacing XXX with your redhat account
# subscription-manager status
# subscription-manager list --available --all
```

If it fails, you might just not have waited long enough for the backend at Redhat to catch up. If it is still failing, try to remove and re-attach the registration.

```
# subscription-manager remove --all
# subscription-manager unregister
# subscription-manager clean
```

Now try to re-attach

```
# subscription-manager register
# subscription-manager attach --auto
# subscription-manager status
# subscription-manager list --available --all
```

You should also see the subscriptions show up in developer.redhat.com subscriptions.

Comment: This works. Like @edt11x said if it fails you didn't wait long enough.

Answer (score 0):

Look here, in the newest version, if I understood correctly, there is no need to use "auto-attach"
https://access.redhat.com/management/subscription_allocations

Answer (score 0):

> As subscriptions are not required to be attached to hosts when SCA is enabled, workflows related to auto-attach are obsolete. You no longer need to:
>
> - Run `subscription-manager attach --auto`
> - Run `hammer host subscription auto-attach`
> - Set activation keys to `auto-attach`
>
> Running the above commands will result in either a no-op (no change) or explicitly error.