# Subscription register error : Ignoring attach when attach pool_id

Tags: linux, rhel

- Hi all, im new to linux and currently working with redhat OS. I'm using version 8.6 and was trying to register to my redhat account to get the repositories there. When I attached pool_id, I got this error :
- [root@c2 ~]# subscription-manager attach --pool=2c946cd0887328c30188b298cd847ae8

Ignoring request to attach. It is disabled for org "17067957" because of the content access mode setting.

- I already tried the solution from this : [What this error message mean please: Ignoring request to auto-attach. It is disabled for org "15824072" because of the content access mode setting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/692749/what-this-error-message-mean-please-ignoring-request-to-auto-attach-it-is-disa) but it didn't work ( My simple content access is always enable )
- I also tried disable the simple content access, it successfully attached a subscription but when I tried to list the available repositories it didn't show anything.
- Can someone help me with this error. Many thanks

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/692749/117549